# How to extract 3D information from a 3D model for calibration?

Tags: 3d-models

I made two "OBJ" 3D models of myself using [Sense 2 scanner](https://www.3dsystems.com/3d-scanners/sense-scanner) and using photogrammetry with [Meshroom](https://alicevision.org/#meshroom).

I would like to extract some information about myself to be able to scale the model properly and to be able to compare the accuracy. For example, distance between shoulders or circumference of the neck/chest. Another option would be to hold a reference parallelepiped and then scale the model based on the known distance between faces.

How can I do that? I can calculate the distance between points I can click using Meshmixer, but circumference or the distance between parallel faces is more difficult. The tools Meshmixer offers for the purpose don't seem to work well.

What are my options?

Comment: Faces are unlikely to be parallel if they come from photogrammetry, and the circumference of a polygon is always a bit tricky.
In lieu of a known prismatic object to measure the dimensions of, perhaps the distance between your eyes could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting various measurements from 3D models is easily done using the following free online tool:

https://0x00019913.github.io/meshy/

I scanned a person using the Sense 2 scanner and I compared the values from meshy for the hip and waist with those measured in real life one day after the scan: the difference was about 1 cm, which can easily be explained by the uncertainties in the choice of the measurement point and moment of the day.

This shows that both the 3D scanner and meshy are quite accurate. The tool is also very easy to use.